# A switch statement that uses an enum representing the current State of my game is not updating to reflect that switch

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, enums, switch-statement, state

I have a button, whose functionality is dependent on what state the game is in. Within the inspector i have the button's OnClick() pointed at a function that contains (A longer and functional version of) the following code:

```
public void Button1(){
Debug.Log ("Pressed");
switch (GameState) {
    case States.aState:
        Debug.Log ("In A");
        Debug.Log (GameState.ToString ());
        //Do stuff
        break;
    case States.bState:
        Debug.Log("In B");
        Debug.Log (GameState.ToString ());
        //Do stuff
        break;
}
```

}

In addition, the test my suspicions, I also have the following Update function (Copied verbatim this time)

```
void Update(){
    Debug.Log (GameState.ToString ());
}
```

The Update function matches what the inspector shows, that the game state is changing. However, the Switch is ignoring this and always goes to the first case, regardless of what the inspector or the Update debug is showing.

In case its relevant, this script also has a DontDestroyOnLoad() command on it, since its holding data, including the GameState variables in this switch, that I need it to carry between scenes.

Any help as to why its doing this would be appreciated.

Edit: Full script for clarity.

```
public class StateManager : MonoBehaviour {
#region Variables
/// <summary>
/// States, referring to the individual scenes of the game. Please refer the the "Outline" Word doc or the individual scene scripts in the "Assets/Scripts/RoomCode" folder for details on each state.
/// </summary>
public enum States {aState=0,bState=1,cState=2,dState=3,eState=4,fState=5,gState=6,hState=7,iState=8,jState=9};
public States GameState = States.aState;
/// <summary>
/// Holds a reference to the current scene's Scenemanager.
/// </summary>
public GameObject curSceneManager;

/// <summary>
/// Holds references to the actual files for scenes, assigned in Inspector.
/// </summary>
public Object[] scenes;

/// <summary>
/// Holds whatever scene is currently open.
/// </summary>
public Scene curScene;

/// <summary>
/// Tracks how many items the player has gathered that would summon Phafnir.
/// </summary>
public int PhafnirScore=0;
/// <summary>
/// Tracks how many items the player has gathered that would summon Baphomet.
/// </summary>
public int BaphometScore=0;

#endregion
/// <summary>
/// Set object references. Done in awake so that all objects are fully loaded.
/// </summary>
void Awake(){
    //Assign curScene
    curScene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene ();

    //Assign curSceneManager
    curSceneManager = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("SceneManager");

    //Assign Delegate Subscription to OnSceneLoad, which will cause that function to be called whenever a new scene is loaded
    SceneManager.sceneLoaded+=OnSceneLoad;

    //set SceneManager to stay loaded between scenes
    DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);

}
void Update(){
    Debug.Log (GameState.ToString ());
}
void OnSceneLoad(Scene scene, LoadSceneMode mode){
    //Assign curScene
    curScene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene ();

    //Assign curSceneManager. Not actually used because of the strange way it conflicts with DontDestroyonload
    curSceneManager = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("SceneManager");
}
/// <summary>
/// The two choice button objects are set to call the following two functions,  
/// </summary>
public void Button1(){
    Debug.Log ("Pressed");
    switch (GameState) {
        case States.aState:
            Debug.Log ("In A");
            Debug.Log (GameState.ToString ());
            if (GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("SceneManager").GetComponent<SceneParent> ().ScriptPlace == 3) {
                curSceneManager.GetComponent<SceneParent> ().ScriptPlace = 4;
            }
            else if (GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("SceneManager").GetComponent<SceneParent> ().ScriptPlace == 5) {
                curSceneManager.GetComponent<SceneParent> ().ScriptPlace = 6;
                curSceneManager.GetComponent<SceneParent> ().choice = SceneParent.choices.button1;
            }
            break;
        case States.bState:
            Debug.Log("In B");
            Debug.Log (GameState.ToString ());
            GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("SceneManager").GetComponent<SceneParent> ().choice = SceneParent.choices.button1;
            GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("SceneManager").GetComponent<SceneParent> ().ScriptPlace++;
            break;
        case States.cState:
            Debug.Log("In C");
            break;
        case States.dState:
            Debug.Log("In D");
            break;
        case States.eState:
            Debug.Log("In E");
            break;
        case States.fState:
            Debug.Log("In F");
            break;
        case States.gState:
            Debug.Log("In G");
            break;
        case States.hState:
            Debug.Log("In H");
            break;
        case States.iState:
            Debug.Log("In I");
            break;
        case States.jState:
            Debug.Log("In J");
            break;
        default:
            Debug.Log ("Error, result for Button1 not found");
            break;
    }
}
public void Button2(){
    switch (GameState) {
        case States.aState:
            break;
        case States.bState:
            GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("SceneManager").GetComponent<SceneParent> ().choice = SceneParent.choices.button2;
            GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("SceneManager").GetComponent<SceneParent> ().ScriptPlace++;
            break;
        case States.cState:
            break;
        case States.dState:
            break;
        case States.eState:
            break;
        case States.fState:
            break;
        case States.gState:
            break;
        case States.hState:
            break;
        case States.iState:
            break;
        case States.jState:
            break;
        default:
            Debug.Log ("Error, result for Button2 not found");
            break;
    }
}
public void Button3(){
    switch (GameState) {
        case States.aState:
            if (GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("SceneManager").GetComponent<SceneParent> ().ScriptPlace == 3) {
                GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("SceneManager").GetComponent<SceneParent> ().ScriptPlace = 5;
            }
            else if (GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("SceneManager").GetComponent<SceneParent> ().ScriptPlace == 5) {
                GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("SceneManager").GetComponent<SceneParent> ().ScriptPlace = 6;
                GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("SceneManager").GetComponent<SceneParent> ().choice = SceneParent.choices.button3;
            }
            break;
        case States.bState:
            GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("SceneManager").GetComponent<SceneParent> ().choice = SceneParent.choices.button3;
            GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("SceneManager").GetComponent<SceneParent> ().ScriptPlace++;
            break;
        case States.cState:
            break;
        case States.dState:
            break;
        case States.eState:
            break;
        case States.fState:
            break;
        case States.gState:
            break;
        case States.hState:
            break;
        case States.iState:
            break;
        case States.jState:
            break;
        default:
            Debug.Log ("Error, result for Button3 not found");
            break;
    }
}
//The next button, when clicked, simply advances to the next part of the room's script
public void Nextbutton(){
    Debug.Log ("OH GOD THEY CLICKED NEXT");
    GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("SceneManager").GetComponent<SceneParent> ().ScriptPlace++;
}
/// <summary>
/// Called by the RoomManager scripts to change scenes as needed.
/// </summary>
public void loadScene(int s){
    //Update state by typecasting
    GameState = (States)s;
    //S represent the scene's load order in the build settings. a=0 up to j=9, in order;
    SceneManager.LoadScene (s);
}
```

}

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that `GameState` in both snippets references the same variable and they are not in different scopes?

Comment: I am completely certain. They are one after the other in my code, on the same script. The update function is place on the line right below where the button1 function ends.

Comment: if you have only two States please rewrite your code with `if..else` statement and let us know if all works

Comment: Like i said, it's a shortened version of the full code. There's about 12 cases, so for readability's sake, id prefer to stick with a Switch statement, but i can certainly try an if-else if to see if it works.

Comment: changing it to an if-Else if still has the same problem

Comment: Is `GameState` static? Since no one can help you with your little sample code, please put EDIT in your question and post the complete script so that people can see what exactly is going on

Comment: Added the full script

Answer (score 0):

Are you adding indices to your Enum? For example does your Enum look like this:

```
public enum States {
  aState = 0,
  bState,
  cState
}
```

if so, try indexing all values:

```
public enum States {
  aState = 0,
  bState = 1,
  cState = 2
}
```

Comment: Adding Indices didn't help the issue, but you're right, it's prudent to do that anyways.

Comment: If you are setting GameState within a tight loop, then it is possible that every time you press that button the state is actually `aState`. If that is the case, what I would do is have a integer variable count how many times GameState was something other than `aState`, and you might find that the code you pasted is actually working properly.

Comment: It's not within a loop, so that isn't the issue i think. I can see in the console that my Debug in Update does return bState, its only in the switch that it doesnt.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized what my problem was. When I move to a new scene, my button's OnClick ends up being pointed at the prefab for my Statemanager, and on the prefab, the GameState is set to aState.

Going to restructure my code to use a AddListener for the button rather than the inspector's OnClick, and have the listener change whenever a new scene is loaded.